# Solve vectorial linear system with cross product

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

**Question:** Does the system bellow have any solution for $\vec{F}_a$ and $\vec{F}_b$? If yes, how can I find them all?

$$
\begin{cases}\vec{F}_a + \vec{F}_b = \vec{F}_r \\
\vec{p}_a \times \vec{F}_a + \vec{p}_b \times \vec{F}_b = \vec{M}_r
\end{cases}
$$

I tried to transform it into a block linear system, but it seems that $\det K =0$:

$$
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\left[I_3\right] & \left[I_3\right] \\
\left[\vec{p}_a\right]_{\times} & \left[\vec{p}_b\right]_{\times} \\
\end{bmatrix}}_{K}
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{F}_a \\
\vec{F}_b \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{F}_r \\
\vec{M}_r \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$[I_{3}]$ is the identity matrix and $[u]_{\times}$ is the [cross product matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) of $u$:

$$
u \times a = \left[u\right]_{\times} \cdot a
$$
$$
u = \left(u_x, \ u_y, \ u_z\right) \Longrightarrow \left[u\right]_{\times} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -u_z & u_y \\ u_z & 0 & -u_x \\ -u_y & u_x & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I used python to get random vectors $p_{a}$ and $p_{b}$ and computed the $K$ determinant. But I'm not sure if it's always true.

Comment: Actually, no, scratch my previous comment. It is always singular! One can use the [block-diagonal determinant formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_determinant)$$\det\pmatrix{A & B \\ C & D} = \det(AD - BC).$$In this case, we get $\det([\vec{p}_a]_\times - [\vec{p}_b]_\times)$, which comes to $\det([\vec{p}_a - \vec{p}_b]_\times)$, which is singular, since it sends $\vec{p}_a - \vec{p}_b$ to $\vec{0}$ (or the matrix is the $0$ matrix if $\vec{p}_a - \vec{p}_b = \vec{0}$).

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Do you mean to find a pair of vectors $\vec{F}_a$ and $\vec{F}_b$ that satisfies the two equations, or to *recover* $\vec{F}_a$ and $\vec{F}_b$, knowing that they satisfy the two equations?

Comment: @user1551, I quite don't understand your question. When solving a linear system like $Ax=b$, do we find $x$ or do we recover $x$ knowing it satisfies $Ax=b$?

Comment: That's precisely what I'd like you to clarify. This isn't a problem if the system of equations has a unique solution. But you system doesn't. It has either no solutions of infinitely many solutions. If you want to recover an existing solution, this is simply an impossible task (because there are infinitely many solutions and we don't know which one is the original), but if you are happy with any solutions, then this is easy. In an answer below, the answerer seemed to think that you want to recover the pair of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By substituting $\vec{F}_b = \vec{F}_r - \vec{F}_a$ into the second equation, you only need to solve
$$
\underbrace{\left(\vec{p}_a-\vec{p}_b\right)}_u\times\underbrace{\vec{F}_a}_x
=\underbrace{\vec{M}_r-\vec{p}_b\times \vec{F}_r}_v
$$
which is in the form of
$$
u\times x=v\tag{1}
$$
where $u$ and $v$ are given and $x$ is the unknown vector. Since the linear map $x\mapsto u\times x$ is singular, equation $(1)$ has either no solution or infinitely many solutions. More specifically,

- if $v=0=u$, every vector $x$ is a solution;
- if $v=0\ne u$, the general solution is given by $x=cu$ where $c$ is an arbitrary scalar;
- if $v\ne0$, the equation is solvable if and only if $0\ne u\perp v$. When this condition is satisfied, the general solution is given by $x=\frac{\|v\|}{\|v\times u\|}v\times u+cu$ where $c$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the determinant of $K$ is $0$ as mentioned by @Theo. That means this system has no unique solution.

We change the first equation to

$$
F_a = F_r - F_b
$$

$$
\Rightarrow p_a \times (F_r - F_b) + p_b \times F_b = M_r
$$

$$
\Rightarrow (p_b - p_a) \times F_b = M_r - p_a \times F_r
$$

As shown in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953254/solving-for-vector-in-cross-product), there's no unique solution to this equation.

If $(F_{a0}, \ F_{b0})$ is a solution, then $\forall \omega \in \mathbb{R}$

$$F_a = F_{a0} - \omega \cdot (p_b - p_a) \\ F_b = F_{b0}+\omega \cdot (p_b-p_a)$$

is also a solution.

**Extra:** For the specific case that $M_r = p_r \times F_r$, the equations would be

$$
F_a + F_b = F_r
$$
$$
p_a \times F_a + p_b \times F_b = p_r \times F_r
$$

We can rewrite the equations to get

$$
(p_b - p_a) \times F_b = (p_r - p_a) \times F_r
$$
$$
(p_b - p_a) \times F_a = (p_b - p_r) \times F_r
$$

It still doesn't have a specific solution. But we expect (for physical reasons) that

- If $p_r = p_a$, then $F_{a0} = F_r$ and $F_{b0} = 0$
- If $p_r = p_b$, then $F_{a0} = 0 $ and $F_{b0} = F_r$
- If $p_r = \frac{1}{2}(p_a+p_b)$, then $F_{a0}=F_{b0}=\frac{1}{2}F_r$

As all the solutions lies on the line $p_b-p_a$, then we can create a parameter $t \in \mathbb{R}$ which tells the relative distance between $p_r$, $p_a$ and $p_b$.

$$
t = \dfrac{\langle p_r - p_a , \ p_b - p_a \rangle}{\langle p_b - p_a, \ p_b - p_a \rangle} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}p_r = p_a \Rightarrow t = 0 \\ p_r = p_b \Rightarrow t = 1\end{cases}
$$

Then we set the solution to:

\begin{align*}
F_{a0} & = (1-t) \cdot F_r \\
F_{b0} & = t \cdot F_r
\end{align*}